# If you run a file.to_csv code in Jupyter as opposed to Google Colab, where does the file go to be downloaded?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

This is the input I'm running: `file = pd.DataFrame({'column': x_test, 'target': y_test}) my_file.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)`.

In G Colab, the file appears in the files folder in the left column and you can download it there. I'm trying to figure how to download it in Jupyter?

Comment: `file.csv` would be in the same path from which you started the `jupyter` command. You can download it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are done with your code as you mention in your question.

1. Click on File.
2. Select Open.

It will open a new tab where you find three menu File, Running, Clusters.

The csv file that you made by the name of "file.csv"  you can find in the File section.